# Configure PHP script to echo back data from remote ssh server array

Tags: php, grep, libssh2

Hi I would like to know if it would be possible to get a response from multiple servers to PHP with a server array?

I am trying to create a script that will grep text on multiple servers, each server has different files but I have a list of all files in the directory of each server stored into a list.txt. I am trying to make the search as fast as possible, I am currently using ripgrep for grepping my data.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('ssh2_connect'))
{
    die("Install ssh2 module.\n");
}
if (isset($_GET['command'], $_GET['text'], $_GET['down'])) {
    $SERVERS = array(
            "10.0.0.3"       =>      array("root", "password")
            "10.0.0.4"       =>      array("root", "password")
            "10.0.0.5"       =>      array("root", "password")
            "10.0.0.6"       =>      array("root", "password")
            );
    class ssh2 {
            var $connection;
            function __construct($host, $user, $pass) {
                    if (!$this->connection = ssh2_connect($host, 22))
                            throw new Exception("Error connecting to server");
                    if (!ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $user, $pass))
                            throw new Exception("Error with login credentials");
            }

            function exec($cmd) {
                    if (!ssh2_exec($this->connection, $cmd))
                            throw new Exception("Error executing command: $cmd");

                    ssh2_exec($this->connection, 'exit');
                    unset($this->connection);
            }
    }
    if($_GET['command'] == "Download") { $command = "wget http://10.0.0.7/data/{$down}.db"; }
    elseif($_GET['command'] == "Search") { $command = "while read filename; do grep {$text} "$filename"; done < list.txt" }
    else die();
    foreach ($SERVERS as $server=>$credentials) {
            $disposable = new ssh2($server, $credentials[0], $credentials[1]);
            $disposable->exec($command);
            echo "<pre>$disposable</pre>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing here?

Comment: on the line with echo "<pre>$disposable</pre>";
It will not echo the data back from the servers and I am not sure how to get it to properly work.